# How to implement inheritance for POJO class

Tags: java, inheritance, sonarqube

I have two different class with constructor but with similar pojo and i wanted to implement java inheritance as while running sonar code analysis gives me code duplicate

I have created the classes DaoException and ServiceException which has same pojo and wanted to have the pojo common to avoid code duplicate

```
public class DaoException extends Exception {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private final int code;
  private String message;


  public DaoException(int code, String message) {

      this.code = code;
      this.message = message;
  }

  public DaoException(int code, Throwable throwable) {

      this.code = code;
      this.message = throwable.getMessage();
  }

  public int getCode() {

      return code;
  }

  public void setCode(int code) {

      this.code = code;
  }

  public String getMessage() {

      return message;
  }

  public void setMessage(String message) {

      this.message = message;
  }
}
```

```
public class ServiceException extends Exception {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private final int code;
private String message;

public ServiceException(int code, String message) {

    this.code = code;
    this.message = message;
}

public ServiceException(int code, Throwable throwable) {

    this.code = code;
    this.message = throwable.getMessage();
}

public int getCode() {

    return code;
}

public void setCode(int code) {

    this.code = code;
}

public String getMessage() {

    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {

    this.message = message;
}
```

}

Please advise.

Comment: Exception classes should be excluded from sonar.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a common parent class for ServiceException and DAOExecption . You can create your class GenericException , with all the details . 
Then make ServiceException and DAOExecption extend this GenericException. Call the appropriate constructor of parent class from the child